# How do I make a "never" filter in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry for being not clear in question title, so I will describe on dataset

```
Id   Item
1    North
1    South
1    West
1    Central
2    North
2    South
2    East
3    North
3    East
```

I want to filter, for example `never West`

```
Id   Item
2    North
2    South
2    East
3    North
3    East
```

This is only display data from `Id` that don't have `West` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df[~df['Id'].isin(df.loc[df['Item'] == 'West', 'Id'])]
print (df)
   Id   Item
4   2  North
5   2  South
6   2   East
7   3  North
8   3   East
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.loc[df['Item'] == 'West', 'Id'])
2    1
Name: Id, dtype: int64

print (~df['Id'].isin(df.loc[df['Item'] == 'West', 'Id']))
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
Name: Id, dtype: bool
```

**Explanation**:

1. First filter `West` and get `Id` values
2. Filter again by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and inverted boolean mask by `~`

Comment: This is my answer as well, I was thinking there are any other function of this

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe is called `df`, you can filter based on `Item` not being equal to `West`:

```
df[df['Item'] != 'West']
```

Comment: Sorry, do you check output?

Comment: I did, but I realise now that I misunderstood what they were asking.